# How does Molecule does the role lookup

Tags: ansible, molecule

Using Molecule 2.19.0 to test it on an Ansible role. Molecule and Ansible both work as desired.

I've got a question regarding *how* molecule executes the Ansible role.

This is my file structure:

```
| my_role (Root of the role)
* defaults
* files
* molecule
   * default
       * tests
           - molecule.yml
           - playbook.yml
           - Dockerfile.j2
           - tests
* tasks
* templates
```

Now, in the `playbook.yml` of **molecule** I set the role name:

```
---
- name: Converge
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - role: my_role
```

When running `molecule test` or `molecule converge`, it will run the role (as expected).

But *how* does Molecule this under the hood? How does it know the role is present in the root directory in this particular use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Molecule does this by setting some sensible defaults for ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH:
[Click me for source code](https://github.com/ansible/molecule/blob/fc90dfd6c8a5fd3a3068b9cc8311dc176ab261cd/molecule/provisioner/ansible.py#L203-L208)

There is also the concept of the ["project directory"](https://github.com/ansible/molecule/blob/adb9fde29c05620be4b3b88e272339d9ec8b93bd/molecule/config.py#L133) which is the directory that molecule is run from. This will be your role directory.